# Confusion between DAL, Service Layer and repositories

Tags: asp.net-mvc, domain-driven-design, repository, extension-methods

Say I have a simple model like these (small part of a pretty large app)

```
public class EHR : IEntity
{
    public int ID { get; set; }        
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreationDate { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<PhysicalTest> PhysicalTests { get; set; }
}

public class PhysicalTest : IEntity
{    
    public int ID { get; set; }    
    public virtual EHR Ehr { get; set; }
    public Boolean IsDeleted { get; set; }
}
```

And i want for an easy way to get the physicalTests that are NOT deleted for a given EHR.

So, I can think of three ways of doing this.

one is simply adding a method to my EHR class.(it doesnt seem as such a bad idea cause I dont want to suffer from [anemic domain model](http://martinfowler.com/bliki/AnemicDomainModel.html))

```
public IEnumerable<PhysicalTest> ActivePhysicalTests()
{
    return this.PhysicalTests.Where(!m=>m.IsDeleted).ToList();
}
```

the other one is creating an extension method under a EHRRepositoryExtensions class:

```
public static class EHRRepositoryExtensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<PhysicalTest> Active(this IEnumerable<PhysicalTest> physicalTests)
    {
        return physicalTests.Where(test => !test.IsDeleted).OrderByDescending(test => test.CreationDate).ToList();
    }
}
```

I also think I could have extended my IRepository to include a method that returns only the physsicalTests that arent deleted.

something like

```
public class EHRRepository : IRepository<EHR>
{
    //TODO: method that returns only the physsicalTests that arent deleted.
}
```

I am still trying to grasp many concepts on DDD and I want it to be as pure as possible.

Which of this approaches would you recommend?
whats a rule of thumb on topics like this?

Please Help.

Comment: Shouldn't this return this.PhysicalTests.Where(!m=>m.IsDeleted).ToList(); be this return this.PhysicalTests.Where(m=>!m.IsDeleted).ToList();, the NOT is wrongly placed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first approach is recommended as EHR is your Aggregate Root and it is the information expert about its physical tests.

Second approach is not relevant as you have already the model and you can add this method to the entity instead.

The third approach would be preferable only if the list of physical tests takes much time to load from the database, still you can utilize lazy loading but if you want to separate the fetching from the domain or you dont use a lazy loading enabled ORM then put it as a query method in the repository